# Procedure para retornar o calculo de rota entre coordenadas através da API do GoogleMaps

Tags: sql, google-maps, rotas, coordenadas

Preciso criar todas as regras de negócio de um sistema dentro do banco de dados e permitir que outras aplicações com a finalidade de serem apenas uma interface gráfica para o usuário utilizem livremente todas as funções disponíveis no banco de dados através de stored procedures.

Dentre elas, preciso criar uma procedure que dadas coordenadas de partida e coordenadas de destino, ela acesse o GOOGLEMAPS e RETORNE a distância EM ROTA (não é em linha reta).

**É possível?**

Comment: Primeiro de tudo, que bando de dados está usando?

Comment: 1 par de varchar pra coordenada de ORIGEM e 1 par de varchar para coordenada de DESTINO, e as aplicações que acessarem essa procedure receberão um valor VARCHAR também...

Eu não tenho nenhum código escrito porque eu não sei se é possível o SQL SERVER acessar uma URL através de uma SP...

Comment: Primeiro de tudo, que bando de dados está usando?